# How will IOTA avoid re-generating old addresses that have been pruned via Snapshots?

Tags: transaction, wallet, seed

Some people are seeing issues where they have generated addresses post-snapshot that were pruned, which are identical to pre-snapshot addresses. This poses a risk because if you re-use these addresses to send iotas, your seed can become compromised.

How will this be avoided in the future to prevent re-using addresses to spend?

Answer (score 3):

## local storage

Wallets would have to keep track of their own adresses, if they already used them and what they already used them for.

## switch seeds

Another solution is to switch seeds after every snapshot and just send all your IOTA to the first address of the new seed.

## Permanode

What would work as well is to ask a Permanode (node that doesn‘t do snapshots but saves the whole Tangle history) about which addresses were already used. Of course you‘d have to trust the node to not lie to you, wait for you using the address and stealing your IOTAs.

---

I think **local storage** is the optimal solution for *most* cases. Of course the other ones will most likely have some use cases as well.

Comment: Whats the point of snapshot if it generates all the addresses after snapshot